# How can I make an Application Insights dashboard metrics chart with two lines (from two Kusto queries)?

Tags: azure, charts, azure-application-insights, metrics, kql

I have this query that gives me a chart with one line:

```
traces
| where message has "abc" 
| summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render timechart
```

Is there an easy way to add another line to this same chart? I want another line but instead of `| where message has "abc"` with `message has "xyz"`

The situation is that I have these two events that supposed to happen an equal number of times, one a couple minutes after the other. So what I'd like to see is a chart with two lines that are more or less the same shape, one shifted by a couple minutes if I brought the time granularity down. If the lines don't match up, then I know something wrong. If they do match up, I have some degree of confidence that nothing is going horribly wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this, using the `countif()` aggregation function:

```
traces
| summarize c1 = countif(message has "abc"),
            c2 = countif(message has "xyz")
         by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render timechart
```

Comment: Thanks Yoni, this is exactly what I was looking for!